# Accessing Cosmos DB from Azure function, slow query speed

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Trying to use Cosmos DB as my data store for a web app I am working on.  The business layer for this is living in Azure functions, so each call is stateless.

Issue is, when I first establish a connection to a container the first query take 2-5 seconds to return.  Subsequent queries are faster but since the backend is stateless the connection is established on each request.

```
Database db = this.cosmosClient.GetDatabase(myDatabaseId);
Container container = db.GetContainer(myContainer);
var resp = container.ReadItemAsync(id, pk)
```

I have also tried to get the container directly, but it had no affect.

```
var x = this.cosmosClient.GetContainer(myDatabaseId, myContainer);
```

I found a few resources referencing this issue, but all the "solutions" were to persist the connection which I cannot do in a stateless environment.

Not sure if there is an actual solution for this.

Comment: Please see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74042984/implement-singleton-on-azure-functions-with-cosmosdb-and-microsoft-azure-cosmos.

Comment: @GauravMantri  Thank you very much.  This seems to be exactly what I need.