# How can I connect to Cosmos DB only once at Startup in Azure Function?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a .NET 6 Azure Function written in C# that does not have any `Program.cs` nor `Startup.cs` classes. It only has all the endpoints that I need in `.cs` files (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and so on).

The function is running correctly but I have a problem with my connection to the Cosmos DB. I want to connect only once at startup of the function and then use that same connection throughout all the other endpoints.

How can I do that? Right now it seems I am creating a new DB object each time and that does not seem to be optimal at all.

Comment: How is this possible? the function is in-process or isolated?

Comment: I don't know, how can I know which type of function it is? It wasn't created by me.

Comment: Look into ``local.settings.json`` file and what is the value for property ``FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME``?

Comment: `"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"`

Comment: So that is in-process and you can use the @Hank answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement Singleton on Azure Functions with CosmosDB and Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74042984/implement-singleton-on-azure-functions-with-cosmosdb-and-microsoft-azure-cosmos)

Comment: I still have to test both answers and then I'll let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Azure SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/performance-tips-dotnet-sdk-v3?tabs=trace-net-core#sdk-usage) states that you *should* use a singleton for your Cosmos DB client.

Here's a sample from Microsoft that uses static methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/performance-tips-dotnet-sdk-v3?tabs=trace-net-core#sdk-usage. However, I would go with function [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection).

My `.csproj`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" Version="3.32.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

`Startup.cs`

```cs
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]

namespace MyFunctionApp;

public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        IConfiguration configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<CosmosClient>((serviceProvider) =>
        {
            return new CosmosClient(configuration["CONNECTION_STRING"]);
        });
    }
}
```

`ProductApi.cs`

```cs
public class ProductApi 
{
   private readonly CosmosClient _client;
   public ProductApi(CosmosClient client) 
   {
        _client = client;
   }

    [FunctionName("GetProducts")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, methods: "get", Route = "products")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        // Get stuff from database/containers.
    }
}
```

This is just a quick example. I would not use the `CosmosClient` directly but instead put it behind some sort of service (don't forget to register it for DI).

```cs
public interface IProductService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Product>> Read();
}

class ProductService : IProductService
{
    private readonly CosmosClient client;
    private readonly Database database;
    private readonly Container container;

    public ProductService(CosmosClient cosmosClient)
    {
        client = cosmosClient;
        database = client.GetDatabase("tailwind");
        container = client.GetContainer(database.Id, "products");
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> Read()
    {
        var feedIterator = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Product>().ToFeedIterator();
        var batches = new List<Product>();

        while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
            batches.AddRange(await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));

        return batches;
    }
}
```